# Debugger not allowing me to step into subsequent functions from entrypoint .py file I specified (VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am trying to debug my python program with the use of the below launch.json configuration.

```
{
    "name": "pysystemtrade",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "/Users/darshildholakia/Documents/pysystemtrade/examples/introduction/prebakedsystems.py",
    "justMyCode": false,
    "subProcess": true,
},
```

Here, I've specified path/to/prebakedsystems.py as the entrypoint as that is the file that kicks off all the processes in this program. I've included a screenshot (same bit of code shown right below the screenshot) of the debugger working fine in the prebakedsystems.py file but when I click continue when I'm at line 36, it doesn't go to the breakpoint I've put in the system.accounts.portfolio() method. Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBEKf.png)

```
from systems.provided.futures_chapter15.estimatedsystem import futures_system

system = futures_system()
result = system.accounts.portfolio().sharpe()
print(result)
```

As a side note I have also tried stepping over and into when I am at line 36 of the screenshot and neither work. I have also tried setting "justMyCode" key to false and true, neither allow me to go to the breakpoint I have set in the system.accounts.portfolio() method.

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using the launch.json? It should work in theory with `justMyCode` set to `false`.

Comment: Yes, the launch.json configuration seems to be picked up by the debugger because I am always taken to the breakpoints I've put in prebakedsystems.py when I launch the debugger. Also, the system.accounts.portfolio() method is source code and not system code so it should work with "justMyCode" being true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the correct launch.json configuration which now allows me to debug throughout the entire system if anyone else is coming across this issue too please see below.

The new launch.json configuration needs to be:

```
{
            "name": "Python: Debug prebakedsystems.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/examples/introduction/prebakedsystems.py",
            "args": [],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First you need to start debugging using the green triangle button in the **Run and Debugging** panel, this will use the configuration in *launch.json*.

[image]

Then you can use `Step Into` action. *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions*

This may also have something to do with your file structure, so if it still fails, please add more information. You can see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)